# Invalid package name when running Bazel under Windows in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel, intellij-plugin

I'm getting this error when running Bazel via IntelliJ:

```
ERROR: Skipping '//src\main:all': Invalid package name 'src\main': package names may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or any of ' !"#$%&'()*+,-./;<=>?[]^_`{|}~' (most 7-bit asc`ii` characters except 0-31, 127, ':', or '\')
```

My main target runs just fine in Powershell.

Here's my .bazelproject file:

```
directories:
  .
  src/main

test_sources:
  src/test
  src/scenarios

targets:
  //:myapp
  //src/main:myapp_lib
  //src/tests:myapp_tests
  //src/scenarios:myapp_scenarios

additional_languages:
  kotlin
```

You can probably guess the layout from that.

I suspect it's a Windows problem just because of the way the `/` has been switched round to `\`, but I have no idea how to solve it. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is most definitely a bug with the IntelliJ with Bazel plugin. It's well supported on Linux, but not as much on macOS and Windows. Could you please file an issue on https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij so we can track this? Feel free to also leave a comment in https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/113

Comment: Done, thank you! Any idea how I might work around this for now?

Comment: You can try this [workaround](https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/1186#issuecomment-633961698)